# Subdirectory "not found" despite rewrite rules in .htaccess that try to show results

Tags: htaccess, error

I'm using a htaccess file in my server but it's returing a "Not Found" error.

The code I'm using is:

```
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex menu.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^/?$                            menu.php [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/([\w-]+)/?$                   results.php?type=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$          results.php?type=$1&id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^read/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$      read.php?title=$1&id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Which is placed inside of the `articles` directory.

But when I visit `localhost/articles/news` I get the error. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/?$                            menu.php [NC,L,QSA]
> RewriteRule ^/([\w-]+)/?$                   results.php?type=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
> RewriteRule ^/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$          results.php?type=$1&id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
> RewriteRule ^read/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$      read.php?title=$1&id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
> ```

None of the `RewriteRule` *patterns* (above) will match a request for `/articles/news` - so yes, you will likely get a 404. In per-directory .htaccess files the `RewriteRule` pattern matches the URL-path *less the directory-prefix*, so the URL-path that is matched does not start with a slash.

I assume this should be routed to `results.php?type=$1` (the second rule)?

However, also note that `RewriteCond` directives only apply to the first `RewriteRule` directive that follows, not all of them, which you seem to be expecting. So, you either need to repeat the `RewriteCond` directives for each rule, or negate the condition and have a single exception at the top. In other words, instead of only applying the `RewriteRule` when the file does not exist. Abort the rewriting process when it does.

So, try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Get out clause... if the request maps to a file or directory then abort
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Request does not map to a file or directory...
RewriteRule ^/?$                           menu.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$                   results.php?type=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$          results.php?type=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^read/([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$     read.php?title=$1&id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

The `NC` (`NOCASE`) flag on the first 3 rules is not required (since the patterns are already case-insensitive). I'd also question whether you need the `NC` flag on the last rule as well (potential duplicate content issue if it is included)? The `QSA` flag is not required on the first rule, since the query string will be appended by default, given that a query string is absent from the substitution.

Since you have the `DirectoryIndex` set, the first rule might not be required anyway?

Comment: Did you manage to get anywhere with this?